# degrees of line bundles over $y^2 = x^3 + 1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

The equation $y^2 = x^3 + 1$ defines an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$.  I could define a line bundle by considering polynomials of "degree" 3 on this space.  How could I do this more precisely?  I have defined an equation in two variables, cutting out a section in affine space:

$$ \{ (x,y) : y^2 - (x^3 + 1) = 0 \} \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2 $$

and in the big space I know that I could use any polynomial in two variables, $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ which is spanned by $x^m y^n$ and there should be a notion of degree:

$$ \deg (x^m y^n ) = m + n $$

and this could correspond to the a $\mathcal{O}(-k)$ with $k = m+n$.  So now we need the [pullback](https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0708-216/216class31.pdf) of that sheaf.  Not knowing any better I'm going to say that:

$$ \deg y^2 = \deg x^3 = 3 $$

Naively I could try to write line bundles of various ranks and hope for the best:

- $\langle 1 \rangle$
- $\langle x \rangle$
- $\langle x^2 \rangle$
- $\langle x^3, y^2  \rangle $
- $\langle x^4 \rangle$

but now I have to say something like $\deg (x^3 + 1) = 3$ which still seems correct but troublesome.  What about if I arrange them into a sort of [ascending chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring) of ideals:

- $\{ 0\} \subseteq \langle 1 \rangle \subseteq \langle 1,x \rangle \subseteq \langle 1,x,x^2 \rangle \subseteq \langle 1,x,x^2,x^3, y^2  \rangle \subseteq \langle 1,x,x^2, x^3, y^2,x^4, xy^2  \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

[Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) have only been around since 1965, but I'm not trying to do anything too compicated here.

Comment: A couple of issues: 1) the collection of polynomials of fixed degree $k$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is not closed under multiplication by $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, so does not determine a line bundle on $\mathbb{C}^2$, and 2) any ideal containing $1$ must be all of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: I dunno, I guess I'm trying to compute the [pullback](https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/725/class21.pdf) of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-3)$ but I'm still tempted to use the affine space $\mathbb{C}^2$, since that's how my original equation was defined. My approach is very naïve and going to be wrong.  That's already been stated. In projective space, my equation will read: $\{y^2 z - x^3 - z^3 = 0\} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: if I recall there's a line bundle that assigns to each point $[a,b,c]$ the line $ax+by+cz=0$.  I think that's what $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ means.